# Ошибка pip3 install pyautogui: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Xlib'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Пытаюсь установить модуль pyautogui, но в терминале вижу ошибку.

```
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/scripts/scsender# sudo -H pip3 install pyautogui
Collecting pyautogui
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/83    /89b5adbc37d1bbf7b486a2c1c00e8037e6f801e8c053c4897bb82d9510c6/PyAutoGUI-0.9.36.tar.gz (46kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 443kB/s 
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-v1q1avhg/pyautogui/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    version=__import__('pyautogui').__version__,
  File "/tmp/pip-build-v1q1avhg/pyautogui/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_x11 as platformModule
  File "/tmp/pip-build-v1q1avhg/pyautogui/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Xlib.display import Display
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Xlib'

 ----------------------------------------
 Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-      build-v1q1avhg/pyautogui/
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас отсутствует модуль Xlib, поэтому и выдаётся ошибка. Попробуйте установить сначала его

```
sudo apt-get install python3-xlib
sudo pip3 install pyautogui
```